# Configuring Backup Exec 2012 using USB hard drives as media

Tags: backup, usb, backupexec

I have found some information on this but have not found the exact answers to these questions.

Background

- I have installed backup exec 2012 (with agents for databases)
- I have configured a storage pool, with 2 USB drives (1TB)
- The backups are configured to backup to one of the 2 drives (depending on which one is connected)

I have 2 questions:

- How do I get Backup Exec to tell me which disk to insert?  I have used tapes before and it told me then which tape to use?  I was hoping this was available for disks too.  (Whilst there are only 2 at the moment, there will be more).
- And then how do I get Backup Exec to delete old backups when the disk if full.

News just in...

Checked with Symantec, and they do not support USB drives for Backup Exec.  Symantec does support USB RDX backup devices, and it 'usually works' with standard USB drives (as per the configuration recommended in this post).

Answer (score 1):

As for the second question: if you've got your media retention settings set correctly then you should wind up with a pretty consistent set of backup files on the USB drives so you shouldn't need to delete any of the B2D files. That being said, I don't know of any way to have BackupExec automatically delete the B2D files. You can manually delete the files but if you're going to do that you want to associate those files with the `Retired Media` media set, delete them from that media set, and then delete the actual files. If you don't follow this procedure you're going to wind up with a very badly messed up Catalog which is going to make restoring data a frustrating, hit-or-miss operation.

Comment: Thanks Joe.  I have adjusted the retention settings.  It's a little annoying because the size of the backups is growing, so the retention days need to be adjusted.

Comment: Right. At some point you'll achieve some balance between the amount of data being backed up, the retention settings and the size of the B2D files on disk... so it will stay fairly static at that point and will only consume additional disk space when the amount of data you back up increases.

Comment: To cover off the first question, I found a link on the Symantec help forums: http://www.symantec.com/connect/forums/be2012-does-not-officially-support-usb-drives-b2d-folders